# Effect of + in vector location brackets [...]

Tags: r, list, vector

```
Test.Vect = runif(101)

n = 90
count.n = 101

Test.Vect[n+1:count.n]

all(Test.Vect[91:101] == Test.Vect[(n+1):count.n])
all(Test.Vect[n+1:count.n] == Test.Vect[(n+1):count.n])
```

Why does line 4 and 5 not match i.e. line 6 fail?

Comment: Use `all`, not `isTRUE`: `all(Test.Vect[91:101] == Test.Vect[(n+1):count.n])`.

Comment: or use: `identical(Test.Vect[91:101], Test.Vect[(n+1):count.n])`

Comment: From the help file `?isTRUE`: *`isTRUE(x)` is an abbreviation of `identical(TRUE, x)`, and so is true if and only if x is a length-one logical vector whose only element is TRUE and which has no attributes (not even names).*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line 6,

```
all(Test.Vect[n + 1:count.n] == Test.Vect[(n + 1):count.n])
```

fails because of operator precedence. The `:` expression is evaluated and then the `+` expression is evaluated.

Take the following example,

```
1 + 1:5
# [1] 2 3 4 5 6
(1 + 1):5
# [1] 2 3 4 5
```

Thus, on line 6 instead of extracting elements 91 through 101 you are extracting elements 90 + (1 through 101) or 91 through 191. Check out the [?Syntax](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Syntax.html) help page for further information on operator precedence.